# How to change the image button when it clicked in menu options

Tags: android-studio, menuitem, imagebutton

I am using image button in options menu and i am trying to change it on click. How can i change that image button when it gets clicked.

For example, in our music player pause and play button and one more subscribe and unsubscribe.

Any suggestions.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_edit, menu);
    if (isEdit) {
        menu.getItem(0).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.drawable_done_all_black));
    } else {
        menu.getItem(0).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_imagebutton_editprofile));
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_edit:
            if (isEdit) {
                updateProfile();
            } else {
                setEditable(true);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();//do not forget to invalidate
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, here what is  'setEditable(true);' i didn't get it - @Rajesh

Comment: you can ignore that method, it was snippet from my project.